# Included pdf's text lies under the new (compiled) pdf's text

Tags: graphics, pdftex, includegraphics

I used the function `\includegraphics*[trim=1cm 1cm 1cm 1cm, clip,page=1]{a.pdf}`to crop out an image from `a.pdf` . Now, after compiling the `.tex` file in `pdflatex`  if I try to  select the text around the imported figure in the newly generated pdf I can see that the pdf `a.pdf`'s text is under that of the new pdf's. How can I fix this?

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    random text
    random text
    random text
    random text
    random text
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics*[page=1,clip, trim=2.3cm 16cm 10.4cm 6cm, scale=.5]{a.pdf}  %Please replace the filename with any pdf with text in the first page
    \end{center}
    random text
    random text
    random text
    random text
\end{document}
```

A picture:

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome! We need to see a minimal working example to help you. See here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/4736

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the pdf to a pdf without text with ghostscript (version 9.15 or newer):

```
 gswin64c -o a-with-outlines.pdf -dNoOutputFonts -sDEVICE=pdfwrite a.pdf
```

Then include the `a-with-outlines`.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!